# Waiting time for Head and Tail consecutively

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Note: I know that there are answers which give the expected number of flips before one gets heads and tails consecutively, but my question is a little different.

Consider a weighted coin where the probability of landing on heads is $p$.

Let A be the event that you get $HT$ consecutively. Express the waiting time for A (number of flips) in terms of Geometric random variables.

My answer:

Condition on the first toss.

1) If the first toss is $T$, we are waiting until we get a $H$, and then after that, we have to continue waiting until we get a $T$.

For example: $TTTTHHHHT$.

So the total waiting time is just $Geo(p) + Geo(1-p)$

2.) If the first toss is $H$, we are waiting until we get a $T$.

For example: $HHHHHT$

So the total waiting time is just $1 + Geo(1-p)$

Can someone please tell me if the above is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree it's a mixture of those two distributions (though you need a "+1" on the first one too). But more simply, isn't it just the time to get a head plus the time to get a tail?

**EDIT**

I'll put my last remark in more detail: You can write the time to get HT as $$T = T_{H} + T_{HT|H}$$ where in my (iffy) notation, $T_H$ is the time it takes to flip your first head and $T_{HT|H}$ is the additional time it takes to complete your $HT$ after you have already flipped a head. By the logic you described in your solution, $T_H\sim Geo(p)$ and $T_{HT|H}\sim Geo(1-p)$ and the two are independent so you can write $$T = Geo(p) + Geo(1-p)$$ (where this time I can blame the iffy notation on you :) )

That this is equivalent to your answer (once you add the plus one to the first term) follows from the one-step recursion equation $$ T = p(1+T_{|H}) +(1-p)(1+T_{|T})$$ and the fact that $T_{|T}$ (bad notation for the additional time it takes to flip $HT$ if the first flip is tails) has the same distribution as $T$ and $T_{|H}$ has the same distribution as my $T_{HT|H}.$

Comment: Can you explain why its (time to get head)+ (time to get tail)? I mean, does it not depend on what the first toss is? If the first toss is a head, I am not sure why it is (time to get head)+(time to get tail)

Comment: If the first one's a head, the (realized) time to get the first head is 1. If not, it's longer. Your approach conditional on the first flip will get you the right answer, but if you just apply your logic unconditionally you'll get the right answer too

Comment: wrote a more thorough answer